# Auto format javascript code in Android Studio

Tags: autoformat

Android studio allows to auto format HTML code but not JavaScript. Is there anyway i can achieve such thing? I already looked for plugins and file types, but it seems like nothing really helped.

what i have already tried:

1. import CSS & JavaScript file types:
   https://github.com/manifestinteractive/android-studio-filetypes.
2. installed JS toolbox plugin.

Comment: Good question, just give a better structure. Provide some examples of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer and ended up installing Visual Studio in order to "beautify" the code. No need for extensions, you select your file and use `CTRL+SHIT+I` and `CTRL+S` to auto format JS code.